# Jquery CSS for inner div that has overridden color for opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, settimeout

I have this html:

```js
$('.allOfMyElementsLikeThisByClass').hover(inFunction, outFunction);

function inFunction() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).children('.nshow').css("color", "rgba(146,151,154, 1)");
  }, 200);
}
function outFunction() {
 $(this).children('.nshow').css("color", "rgba(146,151,154,0)");
}
```

```css
.nshow {
  color: rgba(148, 51, 54, 0);
}

.alwaysshow {
  color: rgba(148, 51, 54, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='allOfMyElementsLikeThisByClass'>
  <div class='nshow'>
    <div class='alwaysshow'>This should always show</div>
    , but this should show up when I want.
  </div>
</div>
```

If I call the class directly, it will behave correctly and set the color value. If I try to reference it relatively for simplicity(like I have done many times), it will not reference correctly. It will, however, work completely correctly for opacity. Is there something wrong with the way I am doing this?

Also, this works completely fine without the surrounding `setTimeout` function, so I know the way I am referencing my selector isn't the problem. Also, separating it into a variable before hand doesn't resolve the problem but works without the `setTimeout` function too. `setInverval` has the same issue.

Comment: UPDATE: seems to work in Firefox. Only having issues in Chrome.

Comment: Where is `outFunction`?

Comment: Please add `outFunction` to your snippet.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose for the `setTimeout()`? This could cause your `inFunction` to run after your `outFunction`.

Comment: Sure that leading `.` in `class='.allOfMyElementsLikeThisByClass'` is intentional? If that was the element you wanted to select using jQuery, you'd have to remove the dot in the class assignment in the HTML.

Comment: Also, I'd be surprised if `$(this)` actually contained what you are expecting it to.

Comment: outFunction simply resets with a call that sets css to original states. The dot was a typo that I fixed. I didn't copy code directly for security reasons.

Comment: the `this` var returns `w.fn.init [div#uniwrighte.bloc]` for my code in the wild. bloc is my container that I used `allOfMyElementsLikeThisByClass` to replace.

Comment: `setTimeout` is meant to make the text appear after a hover event finishes for the parent container so that text resize doesn't occur. There are other solutions that work including referencing by id, but the class selector should work and reduces my file size.

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve this with Javascript in the first place? That is a task for CSS, not JS.

Comment: It has to be done in JS because of the way text colors work. I could use keyframes, but it isn't as manageable as this approach. I might switch it to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the setTimeout() function to its own "namespace" allows for execution away from the hover events, allowing the setTimout() function to execute:

```
 function st(event){
                 setTimeout(function(){
                          $(event).attr("style" , "color: rgba(148,51,54, 1)"); 
                        }, 2000);

             }   

function inFunction(){
var event = $(this).children(".nshow");
st(event);
}
```